# Two django project on the same ip address (server)

Tags: python, django, apache, server, mod-wsgi

Is it possible to set two different django projects on the same IP address/server (Linode in this case)? For exmaple, django1_project running on www.example.com and django2_project on django2.example.com. This is preferable, but if this is not possible then how to make two djangos, i.e. one running on www.example.com/django1 and the second on www.example.com/django2? Do I need to adapt the settings.py, wsgi.py files or apache files (at /etc/apache2/sites-available) or something else?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can do either of these.

Comment: FWIW, there is a bit of a discussion about hosting multiple sites in the post http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html This highlights some of the traps you can encounter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's possible to host several Python powered sites with Apache + mod_wsgi from one host / Apache instance. The only constraint : all apps / sites must be powered by the same Python version, though each app may have (or not) its own virtualenv (which is strongly recommended). It is also recommended to use mod_wsgi daemon mode and have each Django site run in separate daemon process group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Linode restrictions, but if you have control over your Apache files then you could certainly do it with name-based virtual hosting. Set up two VirtualHost containers with the same IP address and port (and this assumes that both www.example.com and django2.example.com resolve to that IP address) and then differentiate requests using the ServerName setting in the container. In Apache 2.4 name-based virtual hosting is automatic. In Apache 2.2 you need the NameVirtualHost directive.